# Hide Facebook Photos on Windows 8 tile

Tags: windows-8, privacy, photos, facebook

I have many albums on my Facebook with privacy level set as "only me, so that albums that only I can see.

I do not want them automatically appearing on my Windows 8 Photos Tile as anyone who uses my computer can see this and can look at all of my photos.

Is there a way I can prevent them from being shown? I am not going to delete them off Facebook as this is the only place that I keep them.

Comment: The simple solution would be to disassociate your Facebook account with the application.  Of course you could also just password protect your computer.

Comment: If you want privacy, you should password protect your computer. If you don't want to lose the photos, you should back them up offline.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Charms bar by swiping in from the right or hovering the mouse at the right edge of the screen
2. Tap/click **Settings**
3. Tap/click **Options**
4. Uncheck the box beside **Facebook**

Alternatively, you can turn off the live tile by right-clicking on the tile from the Start screen and tapping/clicking **Turn Live Tile Off** in the bottom app bar.

Or another thing (as mentioned in the question comments) is to password protect your account and create user accounts for other users, or to turn on the Guest account if they don't require a permanent account.